# display menu using css according to space available on page

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

In my project, we are using vertical menu with sub-menu list 
when user hover on menu, sub menu is displayed on right side of menu.
This works fine for top-most menus, But when user hover on last menu, sub-menu list increases page size.

I wanted the menu work like, when user hover bottom menu list, and if space is not available at bottom then menu should be displayed from bottom-to-top not top-to-bottom

**css**

```
.cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
}

    .cssmenu ul li {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        padding-top: 10px;
        line-height: 26px;
    }

        .cssmenu ul li.hover,
        .cssmenu ul li:hover {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 599;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: powderblue;
        }

            .cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
                visibility: visible;
            }

    .cssmenu ul ul {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 598;
        width: 150px;
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

        .cssmenu ul ul a {
            padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
        }

        .cssmenu ul ul li {
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            border-radius: 7px;
            float: none;
            line-height: 5px;
            padding-top: 0;
        }

            .cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
                background-color: powderblue;
            }

.cssmenu span,
.cssmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.cssmenu li:hover > a,
.cssmenu li.active > a {
    cursor: pointer;
```

}

Comment: Can you post your html and a fiddle please?

Comment: like right click in windows? when the user right clicks at top of the window menu will open from top to bottom, conversely when hit right click at the bottom of the screen, right click menu will open from bottom to top

Comment: @Alek menus coming from server

Comment: You would need javascript, and not a 1-liner either. You would need to be able to detect the distance to the bottom of the window from the `li` element being clicked and if that distance is less than the height of the `ul` that follows then remove/add classes to make the list open bottom to top.  this would be fairly complex. You will need to do some research, try something, show us what you tried, then ask for help.